# Shopware 6 - Admin API : The resource owner or authorization server denied the request

Tags: api, shopware, shopware6

I want to create a new own route API using admin API. I tried this code :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace TestApi\Controller\Api;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"api"})
 */
class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    protected EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/api/product", name="api.product.search", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getProducts(Context $context): JsonResponse
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        return new JsonResponse($this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context));
    }
}
```

When I try this request {baseUrl}/api/product in storefront I get this error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"9","status":"401","title":"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.","detail":"Missing \u0022Authorization\u0022 header","meta":{"trace":[{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/league\/oauth2-server\/src\/AuthorizationValidators\/BearerTokenValidator.php","line":93,"function":"accessDenied","class":"League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException","type":"::","args":["Missing \u0022Authorization\u0022 header"]}
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to provide the `Authorization` header in the request to your admin-api endpoint. The header should include a valid token. To retrieve the token you must first request the corresponding endpoint:

```json
// POST /api/oauth/token

{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "...",
    "client_secret": "..."
}
```

You'll get a `client_id` and `client_secret` by [creating an integration in the administration](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/system/integrationen) of your shop.

This endpoint will then return a temporarily valid token:

```json
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 600,
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

You then take the `access_token` and in all your following requests to the api you set it for `Authorization` in the request header, prepended by `Bearer`:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If you're using a javascript client like axios the object for the headers then would look like this for example:

```js
{
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! these steps I put them to execute the request in postman. But do I have to implement this configuration in the controller or do I just have to follow this documentation using admin api [https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/add-store-api-route#overview] ?

Comment: Shopware handles the authorization for the admin api automatically. You don't have to implement it in your custom controller. Just follow the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two API's, one for [Admin](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEwODA3NjQx-authentication) use (starts with `/api/`), one for [Storefront](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/8e1d78252fa6f-authentication-and-authorisation) (`/store-api/`). As you can see, you are not using the storefront API, and therefore expected to provide the appropriate `Bearer` token.

Moreover, please check that `/api/product` route already [exists](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c2NoOjE0MzUxMjgy-product) in the admin API.
Another thing, I think there is some confusion between a controller & an API route implementation. Maybe you could follow the official [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/add-store-api-route#overview) on it or look it up online?